# Upload image to MySQL in Flask

Tags: python, mysql, flask, flask-mysql

How to upload an image to database `mysql` in `flask`?

I want to upload an image to databases `mysql` in `flask`

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, flash, session
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL

app = Flask(__ name __)
app.secret_key = ""

app.config["MYSQL_HOST"] = "localhost"
app.config["MYSQL_USER"] = "root"
app.config["MYSQL_PASSWORD"] = ""
app.config["MYSQL_DB"] = "journal_flask"


mysql = MySQL(app)
```

Comment: I would keep image on disk and insert only its name in database.

Comment: It seems module `flask_mysqldb` doesn't have special function to work with database - only `execute(SQL)` - so you need only correct `SQL` for this.